# Projection of inner product spanned by orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal

So the question asks: Consider the inner product $⟨f,g⟩=$$ \begin{align} \int_{-1}^{1} f(x)g(x) \ dx &\end{align}$$
 $ on $P_2$, the space of all polynomials of degree 2 or less.
Find the projection of $f=x^2+6x$ onto the subspace W of $P_2$ spanned by the orthonormal basis $g_1=1/2$ and $g_2=  \sqrt{\,1.5 }\ $x. Find $proj_W(f). $

So so far I have:

Because the orthonormal basis are given, then I calculated and got:

||1/2|| =  $  \sqrt{\,0.5 }\ $

||$\sqrt{\,1.5 }\ $x|| = 1

then I have an orthogonal basis:

1/ $  \sqrt{\,0.5 }\ $ * 0.5  and 1/1*$\sqrt{\,1.5 }\ $x

So the $proj_W(f) = 2<0.5,f>0.5+1<\sqrt { 1.5 } x,f>\sqrt { 1.5 } x$ =1/3+6x

However, the answer was wrong. So where exactly was wrong?

Comment: I'm surprised the question gives you an othonormal basis which is not an orthonormal basis... Anyways, why the coefficient 2 in front of $\langle 0.5,f\rangle$?

Comment: @bartgol Yes, I followed  the steps on the textbook. So 2 I think is basically the square of 1/(0.5^0.5). Like the coefficient of <1.5^0.5x,f> is 1^2 which I just omitted.

Comment: The coefficient should not be squared.

Comment: @bartgol Why not? The orthogonal projection of $\mathbf v$ onto $\mathbf u$ is ${\langle\mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle\over\langle\mathbf u,\mathbf u\rangle}\mathbf u = {\langle\mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle\over\|\mathbf u\|^2}\mathbf u$.

Comment: Looks OK to me. Are you sure you’ve got the correct basis? The fact that it’s not actually orthonormal makes me suspicious.

Comment: @amd Yes it was so confusing though.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right.

Comment: @Kior Why do you say the answer is wrong then? Is it from a book? Sometimes books answers are wrong...